# Alternative IconApp bug

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Please tell me. Added the functionality of an alternative change of application icons. Everything works and the icon changes to the main screen of the phone. But it does not change in the list of open applications. What could be the reason?

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rMyO.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9klZ.png)

```
final class AppIconServiceImplementation: AppIconService {
    var currentIcon: AppIconType {
        return AppIconType.allCases.first(where: { $0.name == UIApplication.shared.alternateIconName }) ?? .classic
    }

    func setIcon(_ appIcon: AppIconType, completion: @escaping (Result<Void, Error>) -> Void) {
        guard currentIcon != appIcon,
              UIApplication.shared.supportsAlternateIcons else {
            return
        }

        UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName(appIcon.name) { error in
            if let error = error {
                let message = "Error setting alternate icon \(appIcon.name ?? ""): \(error.localizedDescription)"
                completion(.failure(Error(message)))
            }

            completion(.success)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried quitting and restarting the app after you change the app icon?  From memory, the icon shown in the app switcher will only change after the app has been restarted.

Comment: The application icon in the list of open applications changes only after the phone is restarted (

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a bug in iOS (I'm running 16.3.1). One of my own apps and the Ivory app claimed to change the app icon, but the home screen and app switcher kept showing the old icon. (You said the home screen icon changed for you, but it didn't for me.)

After rebooting my phone I could then see the new icons on the home screen and app switcher. Strangely, changing the icon again in both apps worked and the home screen and app switcher changed.

Comment: Do you think it can be fixed without restarting applications?

Comment: I didn’t test restarting the application, only the whole phone. I am only guessing that it is an iOS bug based on what I saw. It is strange that you saw the Home Screen icon change but not the app switcher when I didn’t see either icon change until I rebooted. I have no idea how many users will see the problem in the real world.